# No way to run pymongo with gunicorn?

Tags: django, pymongo, gunicorn

Seems like pymongo cannot be ran with gunicorn?

My stack is Django + MongoEngine (wrapper to pymongo) and now trying to implement web sockets (gevent), so that it requires to run with gunicorn server. However, when running with Gunicorn. The landing page which does not require any database hit, it loads fine, but after logging in (hits db) it does funky thing and returns "AssertionError: ids don't match" error in all pages.

Did any one experience the same thing as me? if you know the solution, please let me know.

I'm running Django 1.4 + pymongo 2.2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading pymongo to 2.4.1 helped. Works without any issue.